# How does Storing a return value in a pointer from a pointer -to- array of function pointers work?

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

This example (7.19) was taken out of C++ Primer 6th ed by Stephen Prata.

```
#include <iostream>
// various notations, same signatures 
const double * f1(const double ar[], int n);
const double * f2(const double[], int);
const double * f3(const double *, int);

int main()
{
using namespace std; 
double av[3] = { 1112.3, 1542.6, 2227.9 };

// pointer to function 
const double *(*p1)(const double *, int) = f1; 
auto p2 = f2; // C++11 automatic type deduction 
// pre-C++11 can use the following code instead 
// const double *(*p2) (const double *, int ) = f2; 
cout << "Using pointers to functions:\n"; 
cout << " Address  Value\n"; 
cout << (*p1)(av, 3) << ": " << *(*p1)(av, 3) << endl; 
cout << p2(av, 3) << ": " << *p2(av, 3) << endl; 

// pa an array of pointers 
// auto doesn't work with list initialization 
const double *(*pa[3])(const double *, int) = { f1, f2, f3 };
// but it does work for initializing to a single value 
// pb a pointer to first element of pa 
auto pb = pa;
// pre-C++11 can use the following code instead 
// const double *(**pb) (const double *, int) = pa; 
cout << "\nUsing an array of pointers to functions:\n"; 
cout << " Address  Value\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cout << pa[i](av, 3) << ": " << *pa[i](av, 3) << endl; 
cout << "\nUsing a pointer to a pointer to a function:\n";
cout << " Address  Value\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    cout << pb[i](av, 3) << ": " << *pb[i](av, 3) << endl;

// what about a pointer to an array of function pointers 
cout << "\nUsing pointers to an array of pointers:\n";
cout << " Address  Value\n";
// easy way to declare pc 
auto pc = &pa; 
// pre-C++11 can use the following code instead 
// const double *(*(*pc)[3])(const double *, int) = &pa;
cout << (*pc)[0](av, 3) << ": " << *(*pc)[0](av, 3) << endl; 
// hard way to declare pd 
const double *(*(*pd)[3]) (const double *, int) = &pa;
// store return value in pb 
const double * pdb = (*pd[1]) (av, 3);
cout << pdb << ": " << *pdb << endl; 
// alternative notation 
cout << (*(*pd)[2])(av, 3) << ": " << *(*(*pd[2]))(av, 3) << endl; 
// cin.get();
return 0;
}

// some rather dull functions 

const double * f1(const double * ar, int n)
{
return ar; 
}
const double * f2(const double * ar, int n)
{
return ar + 1; 
}
const double * f3(const double * ar, int n)
{
return ar + 2;
}
```

Whats going on with the pointer ***pdb**? is the pointer taking the whole array or just that one element? When the program runs, an exception is thrown where ***pdb** is declared. Can someone tell me whats going on inside?

Comment: "C++ Primer 6th ed by Stephen Prata." - Prata did _not_ write "C++ Primer" - he wrote "C++ Primer Plus", a very bad learning resource.

Comment: The code doesn't look great indeed.

Comment: Any better suggestions to learn from?

Comment: The real "C++ Primer"? Written by people that actually worked on the implementation of C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pdb` is just a pointer like any other. It's returned by a function call, to `f2`.

As it's just a pointer, it points to one element. It's up to you, to the function you called and its contract, to know if there are still elements after or not.